# Detect pattern in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I need to be able to detect patterns in a string in Python. For example:

xx/xx/xx (where x is an integer).

How could I do this?

Comment: Looks like you want to detect dates. There are plenty of questions that cover that already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to match more than just dates, you'll want to look into using Regular Expressions (also called Regex).  Here is the link for the re Python doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html  This will tell you all of the special character sequences that you can use to build your regex matcher.  If you're new to regex matching, then I suggest taking a look at some tutorials, for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for regular expressions. The best resource to start out that I have read so far would be from a book called "Automate The boring Stuff with Python.

This is just a sample of how you migth implement regular expressions to solve your problem.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\d\d\/\d\d/\d\d$')
mo = regex.findall("This is a test01/02/20")

print(mo)
```

and here is the output

```
['01/02/20']
```

Imports python's library to deal with regex(es)
    import re

Then you ceate a regex object with:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\d\d\/\d\d/\d\d')
```

This migth look scary but it's actually very straight forward. 
Youre defining a pattern. In this case the pattern is \d\d or two digits, followed by / then two more  and so on.

Here is a good link to learn more

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Thou I defenetly suggest picking up the book.